# SQL date format and quoting confusion

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have the following test record:

[image]

The following query results in 0 records:

```
SELECT * FROM `events_dates` WHERE `start_date` = 21-12-2014
```

But the following query results in 1 record:

```
SELECT * FROM `events_dates` WHERE `start_date` > 21-12-2014
```

I'm a bit confused about that.

As a side question: is it ok to use the 'date' type if I will not use the time field, or would you still rather choose to use 'datetime'?

Answer (score 7):

You have to single-quote the date literals in the format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. Otherwise, what MySQL is interpreting is an arithmetic expresssion (integer subtraction):

```
21 - 12 - 2014 = -2005
```

The negative integer `-2005` is cast to a date value of effectively `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, which explains why your query with `>` returns a row.

The correct SQL expression would be:

```
SELECT * FROM `events_dates` WHERE `start_date` = '2014-12-21'
```

Regarding the use of the `DATE` type instead of `DATETIME`, yes, I would consider it okay to use it without the time portion if you know you never intend to use times.  I would admit though, that most of the time, I do use `DATETIME` for future expandability. It really depends on your future needs.

If the concern is optimization of storage space to avoid storing the time with `DATETIME`, consider how much potential this table has to grow very large before worrying about optimizing it (it'd have to be *really huge* to matter).  If you do use `DATETIME` instead, you may find yourself frequently using the `DATE()` function to truncate the values at query-time. I consider that to be only a very minor inconvenience.

The same query if `start_date` was a `DATETIME` column can use `DATE()` to truncate off the time segment:

```
SELECT * FROM `events_dates` WHERE DATE(`start_date`) = '2014-12-21'
```

Comment: Great, no more questions :-) I'll accept in 8 mins.

Answer (score 1):

MySql date field support only `YYYY-MM-DD` date format, this query give you correct result

```
SELECT * FROM `events_dates` WHERE `start_date` > '2014-12-21'
```

Although quote date field with (" or ')